# Is this a good answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was reviewing first answers, and [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/22553/4906) came up

My first instincts were that it wasn't a good answer, but on the other hand, it answers the question, by saying don't let the gas run low.

It seems to lack substance. Is this a poor answer?

Comment: I'd recommend you post up such queries at [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) to get a quicker response.. my hunch is that people don't check-in at Meta as often

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think it answers the question. It simply provides a workaround instead. To me the question is asking to explain how the fuel level and the symptoms are related and how to permanently solve the problem so low fuel will not cause this problem.

So while I think its helpful, since he provides the model of another vehicle with the same issue, which can be used to pinpoint the root cause, I also think it should be a comment rather than an answer.